# Assign a temporary key/value pair to a Contact in salesforce Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to the language used in salesforce Apex Triggers:
I'm listening to change on a field and sending the current and previous data values to an external API. But I am not able to set the custom fields to send it to the HTTPRequest method present in `ContactUpdateToExternalService` class with method `callApi`. I don't want these properties to be Custom fields on SObject. I want to use it just for the current instance of trigger execution.

```
trigger ContactUpdate on Contact (after update) {
    for (Contact contact : Trigger.New) {
        if (trigger.newMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId != trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId) {
            Map<Object, Object> data = new Map<Object, Object>contact;
            data.previousAccountId = trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId;
            data.currentAccountId = trigger.newMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId;
            ContactUpdateToExternalService.callApi(JSON.serialize(data));
        }
    }
}
```

The data values are sent to external API services.
I don't want these properties added to `Contact` sObject, when I use the same trigger for before update.

Answer (score 2):

Maps need to use get and put, rather than accessed directly. Also, you should use a `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Map<Object, Object>`:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new Map<String, Object>();
data.put('previousAccountId', trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId);
data.put('currentAccountId', trigger.newMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId);
ContactUpdateToExternalService.callApi(JSON.serialize(data));
```

Or, you can do it all in one step:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new Map<String, Object> {;
  'previousAccountId' => trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId,
  'currentAccountId' => trigger.newMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId
};
ContactUpdateToExternalService.callApi(JSON.serialize(data));
```

However, please note that because of governor limits, you may run into a snag at either 50 (maximum number of asynchronous calls per transaction) or 100 (maximum callouts per transaction) records in a single trigger (e.g. because of an API mass update), so you will probably want to update ContactUpdateToExternalService to support records in bulk, so that you can write:

```
String[] payloads = new String[0];
for(Contact contactRecord: Trigger.new) {
  if(Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).AccountId != contactRecord.AccountId) {
    payloads.add(
      JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, Object> {
          'previousAccountId' => trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id).AccountId,
          'currentAccountId' => contactRecord.AccountId
        }
      )
    );
  }
  ContactUpdateToExternalService.callApiBulk(payloads);
}
```

You'll need to factor in the 100 callout limit in your callApiBulk method, probably by using a Queueable chain (e.g. the Queueable calls itself recursively until all records are sent).

As an aside, you may not have heard of [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm). This feature in Salesforce lets external systems subscribe to changes automatically. You may want to see if your external system supports CDC.

Comment: Using Change Data Capture, we listen to every update. right? But I want to get updates on only a few fields on the `sObject`. 
In the answer, I want to add new fields to the contact object. But it just creates a new Object with only two fields.

Comment: @ashr81 Your question wasn't clear on that. You can include the other Contact data if you want by using [getPopulatedFieldsAsMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm), clone the map, and add in the additional values you want to write.